# Kuzzle V2 Realtime subscription on android sdk v23

Tags: java, android, real-time, real-time-data, kuzzle

We have kuzzle V2 as a broker, and as a data warehouse. Our android devices will subscribe to a collection record, and get updates in realtime.

but the android version we are supporting is <7, which uses java 7
but there is no kuzzle sdk for java other than java 8

any suggestions on how to make an android device real-time subscribe to a collection record with record id in java 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just released a JVM SDK, written in Kotlin and compatible with Java 6+
It's very similar with the now deprecated Java SDK, and you can find here how to migrate from it: https://docs.kuzzle.io/sdk/java/3/migration/how-to/